# JSON object with empty array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've created an application for converting a table to JSON object, the application is working fine but the problem is that an empty array is first appearing for the body key.
can anyone tell me some

```
{"head":["Person Name","Person Name","Points","Price","Tax"],"body":[[],["Jill","Smith","50","150","41"],["Eve","Jackson","94","250","81"],["John","Doe","80","950","412"],["Adam","Johnson","67","750","941"]]}
```

my script is given below

```
$('#convert-table').click( function() {
    try{
var myTable = [];
var myTr =[];
$('#example-table tr').each(function (i, tr) {
    var myTd =[];
    $('th', tr).each(function(j, th) {
          myTr.push($.trim(th.innerHTML));
    });

    $('td', tr).each(function(j, td) {
        if(td.innerHTML.indexOf("span") != -1){
            var text = $(this).closest('td').find('span').text();
            myTd.push($.trim(text));
        }
        else{
            myTd.push($.trim(td.innerHTML));
        }
    });


    myTable.push(myTd);
});

var headObj ={
    head:myTr,
    body:myTable
};
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cCzqn/147/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use condition to check if an array is not empty

**Updated**: Because for the first TR you have only th instead of td that's why your array is empty.

For instance

```
if(myTd.length > 0)
      myTable.push(myTd);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because in the first `<tr>` you only have `<th>` tags, yet you still push to `myTable`, so that's where the empty array is coming from.

only push to `myTable` when you have actual `<td>` to push to it.

You could do this by checking the current row doesn't have any `<tr>` tags in it or checking that the `myTr` array has already been pushed to, indicating you've already passed the row with the `<th>` in it.